# How to upgrade cmake in Ubuntu

Tags: cmake

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  CMake 3.6.0 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.5.1
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I know Ubuntu uses stable releases that it can support, but some repos require later versions of cmake. I want to overwrite the old cmake with the later version of cmake, but the common PPA doesn't carry the cmake I need. How can I upgrade cmake to use the needed version without conflicts with the older version?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

**Warning -- Do not do step 2 if you have [Robot Operating System (ROS)](https://www.ros.org/) installed**

1. Check your current version with:

   ```
   cmake --version
   ```
2. Uninstall it with:

   ```
   sudo apt remove cmake
   ```
3. Visit https://cmake.org/download/ and download the latest bash script.

   - In my case `cmake-3.6.2-Linux-x86_64.sh` is sufficient.
4. Copy the script to `/opt/`.
5. Make the script executable:

   ```
   chmod +x /opt/cmake-3.*your_version*.sh
   ```
6. Change to desired installation directory (to `/opt/` for example)

   - As of cmake 3.10.2 the installer no longer seems to install to `/opt` by default
7. Run:

   ```
   sudo bash /opt/cmake-3.*your_version*.sh
   ```

   You will need to press `y` twice.
8. The script installs the binary to `/opt/cmake-3.*your_version*` so in order to get the `cmake` command, make a symbolic link:

   ```
   sudo ln -s /opt/cmake-3.*your_version*/bin/* /usr/local/bin
   ```
9. Test your results with:

   ```
   cmake --version
   ```

Comment: Don't think you need to uninstall the old `cmake` because `/usr/local/bin` is ahead of `/usr/bin` in `PATH`. So once you make the symlink in your last step, the `cmake` command will call your new `cmake` instead of the old one.

Comment: Yep, but based on what I read on other forums, most users would rather avoid the potential confusion

Comment: As observed by Matt, **IF YOU ARE A ROS USER DO NOT RUN "REMOVE CMAKE"**

Running this command will remove the current cmake version but will also remove parts of your ROS distribution, breaking everything and forcing you to re-install EVERYTHING related to ROS. A warning should be added to this command, or at the very least the leading answer should include a way to update cmake, rather than remove-and-replace.

Comment: ROS... "Robot Operating System"?

Comment: I'm running this in a container by script, so would I need to pass two "y"'s into the script? Are they planning on making `cmake` able to upgrade itself?

Comment: As of cmake 3.10.2 the installer no longer seems to install to `/opt` by default but rather to the current directory, so step 6 needs to be amended accordingly by the user.

Comment: i did all that but once i type cmake --version it says command Cmake not found :(

Comment: @JorgeGT, what to do in this case? I got stuck on that step! cmd gives an errors `-bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory` when typing `cmake --version`

Comment: @Cs20 I had to do `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/cmake /usr/bin/cmake` on Ubuntu 16.04 for the same problem.

Comment: and nobody explains what ROS is...

Comment: It works for me on Windows Subsystem for Linux with CMake 3.16.4

Comment: Just in case someone else makes the same mistake : in the last step provide the **full path** of CMake binaries to the symbolic link. Otherwise bash still can't find the files.

Comment: Actually, it will not be installed in /opt/ if you press "y" twice. Because the second "Y" is to confirm you want it to be installed in your home/user, inside a subfolder. So, symlink would point to there and not to /opt/

Comment: @axd ROS is "Robot Operating System" https://www.ros.org

Comment: CMake 3.16 or higher is required. You are running version 3.5.1. Is that a joke? I am on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @bhordupur No... 16 > 5.

Comment: For anybody reading down to here, I completely recommend this video on how to install the latest version of cmake in your linux system, without removing your previous version: https://youtu.be/_yFPO1ofyF0 . It works perfect, and the author of the video explains every step in detail.

Comment: **Tips for doing this with no problems**:  1. use tab for completing `/opt/cm` ... `TAB`. 2. Don't forget `/` before `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: How can I automate pressing `y` twice? Trying to install in docker

Comment: @Gulzar You can install it with the flag "--skip-license " and it doesn't ask about license.

Comment: cmake complained about not finding things when installed using this method.  What worked for me was installing directly in `/usr/local/` rather than installing in `/opt/` and then creating links.  The command would be `sudo bash <path/to/script>/cmake<version>.sh --skip-license --exclude-subdir --prefix=/usr/local`

Comment: I'm writing a Dockerfile to put cmake into it, the working directory is simply /, hence in step 8 I do `sudo ln -s /cmake-3.*your_version*/bin/* /usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 61):

In the new version of cmake (ex: 3.9.6), to install, download tar file from https://cmake.org/download/. Extract the downloaded tar file and then:

```
cd $CMAKE_DOWNLOAD_PATH
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I like this solution because it is arguably the purest way to solve the problem.  (Just build the software.)  No mucking around with PPAs or anything.  Thanks!

Comment: This is a self-consistent solution. It works for me.

Comment: I did this to update to 3.17 but after sudo make install I get this                              CMake Error: Could not find CMAKE_ROOT !!!
CMake has most likely not been installed correctly.
Modules directory not found in
/usr/local/share/cmake-3.16
cmake version 3.16.3

Comment: First had to install OpenSSL to make it work: "sudo apt-get install libssl-dev"

Comment: solving : "Could not find CMAKE_ROOT" --> open new terminal (source bashrc), now run cmake --version

Answer (score 2):

I would like to follow your advice Wolf, but the script don't install the prog.
So i just creat the folder but doesn't show like installed when i do

```
 cmake --version
```

I find a other way peraps more easy :

```
sudo -E add-apt-repository -y ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
sudo -E apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cmake
```

Comment: I tried this and it updated from 2.x to 3.2.2, but my build script still says "CMake 3.5.1 or higher is required." Is it possible to specify the `add-apt-repository` to be an even later version than 3.x, say something like "3.5.x" ?

Comment: Tis limited to version `3.5.2-2` while current distributes support `3.10.2`