# How to Upgrade CMake in ARM based Ubuntu?

Tags: compiling, arm, cmake

I managed to upgrade CMake on my PC following this link [How to upgrade cmake in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829310/how-to-upgrade-cmake-in-ubuntu) . But now I want to upgrade CMake on my Nvidia Jetson TX2 which is ARM architecture based and the steps on that link doesn't work (only works well with x86). 
1 of Nvidia moderator confirms it, see https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1048533/jetson-tx2/how-to-install-cmake-3-8-in-jetson-tx2-/post/5321354/?offset=3#5321357 .

My current CMake version is 3.5.1 because it was installed using `sudo apt-get install cmake` and I need to install the latest version of CMake. Anyone has experience of upgrading CMake to the latest version in ARM based Ubuntu like Jetson TX2?

Comment: Thanks for asking. If we run `apt-get install cmake` at x86_64 instruction set, will it bring the latest stable release version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. I have built CMake from source using these steps:

```bash
sudo apt remove cmake
wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.8/cmake-3.8.2.tar.gz
tar xf cmake-3.8.2.tar.gz
cd cmake-3.8.2
./configure
sudo make install
cmake --version
```

If after `cmake --version` cmake is still not found, we have to add the installed cmake bin directory path in `.bashrc`:

```bash
vim ~/.bashrc
export PATH=/home/ubuntu/cmake-3.8.2/bin
#save
source ~/.bashrc
cmake --version
```

Comment: You forgot to do `tar -xf cmake-3.8.2.tar.gz` after the wget to decompress and untar your .tar.gz file.