# Problem with cmake ../ gazebo in Ubuntu

Tags: cmake

I have used this instruction:
[How to upgrade cmake in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829310/how-to-upgrade-cmake-in-ubuntu/829311#829311)
And after providing last step when I write this in other terminal:

```
cmake --version
```

I have had this error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/cmake: No such file or directory
```

after calling:

```
cmake ../
```

When I try:

```
/tmp/gazebo/build$ sudo cmake ../
```

I have this:

```
[sudo] password for dmitriy: 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

After I use this Answer [Pytest is in PATH but not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/861376/pytest-is-in-path-but-not-found)
I had this error

```
CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:312 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:323 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:312 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:323 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:312 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:323 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:312 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:323 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:312 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:323 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:312 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:323 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:312 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:323 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:312 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:323 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:312 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:323 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:312 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:323 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:312 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:323 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:312 (file):
  file failed to open for writing (Permission denied):

    /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CompilerIdCXX/CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:323 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_WRITE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:6 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID_BUILD)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCompilerId.cmake:59 (__determine_compiler_id_test)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:120 (CMAKE_DETERMINE_COMPILER_ID)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error: Could not open file for write in copy operation /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake.tmp
CMake Error: : System Error: Permission denied
CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:226 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (project)


CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: /tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/3.23.0/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

After i use answer on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31421327/cmake-cxx-compiler-broken-while-compiling-with-cmake  i have got this error

```
    ====== Finding 3rd Party Packages ======
-- Operating system is Linux
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.26") 
-- Checking for module 'freeimage>=3.9.0'
--   No package 'freeimage' found
--   freeimage.pc not found, trying freeimage_include_dir and freeimage_library_dir flags.
--   Looking for FreeImage.h - not found
--  Missing: Unable to find FreeImage.h
--   Looking for libfreeimage - not found
--  Missing: Unable to find libfreeimage
Package protobuf was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `protobuf.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'protobuf' found
CMake Error at /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find Protobuf (missing: Protobuf_LIBRARIES Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /opt/cmake-3.23.0-linux-x86_64/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindProtobuf.cmake:650 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  cmake/SearchForStuff.cmake:34 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:163 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/gazebo/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Comment: Your issue *now* seems to be missing development packages `libfreeimage-dev` and `libprotobuf-dev`

Comment: Hello. what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @David  Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS (Trusty Tahr)

Comment: 14.04 is long past EOL and off topic on this site. Sorry.